# Catchable fatal error: Object of class MongoCursor could not be converted to string

Tags: mongodb, wamp

This is my error when I m trying to view the data from `MongoDB` to a web page.
Using `Wamp` in Windows:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class MongoCursor could not be converted to string
```

What does it mean and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figuredout the the way to remove the error check this code

```html
<?php
// connect to mongodb
$m = new MongoClient();

$db = $m->local;    // select a database
$collection = $db->directors;  // select a collection (table in old DB)
$cursor = $collection->find(); // view all
foreach ($cursor as $doc)
{
    var_dump($doc);
}
?>
```

In the above code the `var_dump()` function is used to show the data type of value or variable so if you use this this can also give you a detail info about size and length of your data in this case and shows result also.

This code is for how to get value from MongoDB and show on a PHP page.